# Search all tables for multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

The below beautiful SP returns the table and columnname and the value 
What I am interested in however is to do this search for multiple values. 
The only thing I want to know is a distinct output of the table/columnname not the value.

So basically I want to know all tables / columnnames in which my values exist
Then from there I can make a dynamic update query to rename these values in the existing columns ()
So searching these values by making a join maybe would be better. 
I also already thought of stacking the entire database in one giant table in which I can then join on a like. But it's a bit of a headache.. any suggestions?

CREATE PROC SearchAllTables
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

`CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END    
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results END`

Comment: Can you please explain with some examples along with excpected and actual result

Comment: This is an interesting way to do this. I wonder if it would be more efficient to find all of the table and field combinations first and then run the dynamic SQL once. Question though, is `@SearchStr` going to be pattern matched? I see the `LIKE` in the dynamic SQL. Either way, one suggestion would be to put a delimiter in the search string and then iterate over those characters delimiter characters in an outside loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it, the purpose was to find all tables in which my values  exists and then based on that create multiple update statements to for example add a prefix to the original values, I ended up doing what I suggested that is to stuff the entire database into 2 columns and join on those columns (compared to looping through this query for each value, this happened to be much faster) :

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
alter PROC [dbo].[SearchAllTables]
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

`CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
            AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'TPV_BE_PRD'
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' 
            )
        END
    END    
END

SELECT distinct ColumnName FROM #Results a inner join OITM b on a.ColumnValue =   b."ItemCode"   COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS END`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version of SQL Server you are using and the functionality that exists for parsing text. I mainly use SQL Server 2005 so I am pretty limited, but you can parse `@SearchStr` and put the values into a temp table and then use that to join back to.

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchStr = N'123|456|789|ABC|DEF|GHI'

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#SearchStrings') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SearchStrings
CREATE TABLE #SearchStrings (ID INT IDENTITY, SearchString NVARCHAR(100))

WHILE @SearchStr <> ''
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #SearchStrings (SearchString) SELECT CASE WHEN @SearchStr LIKE N'%|%' THEN LEFT(@SearchStr, CHARINDEX('|', @SearchStr) - 1) ELSE @SearchStr END

    SET @SearchStr = STUFF(@SearchStr, 1, CASE WHEN @SearchStr LIKE N'%|%' THEN CHARINDEX('|', @SearchStr) ELSE LEN(@SearchStr) END, N'')
END

SELECT * FROM #SearchStrings
```

Or you can just parse the values and use them directly.

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchStr = N'123|456|789|ABC|DEF|GHI'

WHILE @SearchStr <> ''
BEGIN
    PRINT CASE WHEN @SearchStr LIKE N'%|%' THEN LEFT(@SearchStr, CHARINDEX('|', @SearchStr) - 1) ELSE @SearchStr END

    SET @SearchStr = STUFF(@SearchStr, 1, CASE WHEN @SearchStr LIKE N'%|%' THEN CHARINDEX('|', @SearchStr) ELSE LEN(@SearchStr) END, N'')
END
```